# How to write a gatekeeper yelling "Ooooooi" before asking who goes there?

Tags: dialogue

The title sums it up. I would like advice on how to write the yell of a gatekeeper calling to attention the people approaching the gate.

Pretty much like some scenes where they go: "OOOOiiii, who goes there?"

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? [How do I write a shriek?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/37055/34330), [When writing, should I describe a scream instead of having the character yell out "Ahhhh!"](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/60853/34330), [How would I write a squeal?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/49894/34330)

Comment: I did look at those answers before. I decided to still go with this question because I think it adds to the scene the way the gatekeeper yells, and not just writing that he gave a long yell of a couple of vowels and asked who goes there. But I may be wrong. English is not my native language.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is a gatekeeper's yell different from general screaming in a loud voice in your native language?

Comment: It is not different. I just have this scene with this specific yell in mind and I was curious to see how it should be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably

> Oi! Who goes there?

Otherwise

> Hoy! Who goes there?

or

> Ahoy! Who goes there?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahoy_(greeting)

In your specific case, altering a 'standard' spelling by repeating some of the letters has a comedic effect. If that was not your intention, then you are probably better off with the usual capitalization of the first letter, and a 'traditional' spelling.

You can convey a particular tone or accent by using a specific verb (e.g. bellow, belch, echo) and describing the sound (e.g. whether it lasted long past the first echo, or it was just a sudden shriek like the whistling of a kite).